# "ImportError: cannot import name SkipTest" while importing numpy in python

Tags: python, numpy, importerror

I am having problem while importing numpy.

Please fin below version information:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

# python -V
Python 2.6.6
```

I have already installed numpy (re-installed several times) using pip.

```
# pip install numpy
```

However, when I try to import numpy, it shows error as below:

```
# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from numpy.testing.nosetester import _numpy_tester
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import decorators as dec
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .utils import SkipTest
ImportError: cannot import name SkipTest
>>>
```

I have even tried with "yum reinstall python".
In all cases(numpy and python itself) installation completed successfully.
But still having same error as above "ImportError: cannot import name SkipTest".

Any solution of workaround will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Obaid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, newer numpies no longer support python 2.6

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I have to upgrade my python version.
In fact, after installing python2.7 everything is smooth.

I have installed python2.7 followed by numpy as below:

```
yum install python27
scl enable python27 bash
pip2.7 install numpy
```

Then I was able to import numpy using python2.7 cli.

Thanks,
Obaid